# Problem with \includegraphics - file not found!

Tags: graphics, floats, miktex, texmaker, graphs

I am trying to include a graph in a tex document.
I do realize that there have already been several questions asked about this topic, but I think by now I have tried all suggested solutions but none seem to work. This is the minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{C:/Users/felix/Desktop/Bachelorarbeit/TeX/BA_text2/images}}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{gap_v3_v4_AT.png}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Information about my setup:

I am using Texmaker and MiKTeX 2.9.

Things I have tried:

- Absolute and relative paths,
- not initialising a figure environment,
- including the directory where the graph is in the MiKTeX Options-> root directory (was suggested in one of the answers to a similar question)

There is definetly a `.png` file with the same exact name in the folder set by `\graphicspath`.

I would be really grateful for any ideas!

Comment: You *should* be compiling with pdfLaTeX. Are you?

Comment: FFR, put the graphics path inside `"`, so special characters get escaped.

Comment: It should also be said that `\graphicspath` isn't necessary.  You can just say `\includegraphics{relative_path_from_main}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\graphicspath` does not really setup directories. `graphics` (or `graphicx`) only adds the given strings before the file name of the mandatory argument of a `\includegraphics`, tries to open the file and if is successful uses this concatenated file name to include the file. So

```
\graphicspath{{C:/Users/felix/Desktop/Bachelorarbeit/TeX/BA_text2/images}}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{gap_v3_v4_AT.png}
```

would try to load `C:/Users/felix/Desktop/Bachelorarbeit/TeX/BA_text2/imagesgap_v3_v4_AT.png` (note the missing slash before `gap_v3_v4_AT.png`). If `C:/Users/felix/Desktop/Bachelorarbeit/TeX/BA_text2/images` is the name of a directory, you should append a slash at the end:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{C:/Users/felix/Desktop/Bachelorarbeit/TeX/BA_text2/images/}}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{gap_v3_v4_AT.png}
\end{document}
```

In this example `graphicx` will try to load `C:/Users/felix/Desktop/Bachelorarbeit/TeX/BA_text2/images/gap_v3_v4_AT.png`.

BTW: `\includegraphics` does not need a `figure` environment. `figure` environments makes sense only, if LaTeX should move the `figure` if it could not be printed in place. Mostly `figure` without `\caption` makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can try to finish your `\graphicspath` statement with a double slash (`//`)
2. Check the path that you registered in `\graphicspath`. Many times the file doesn't compile because of a small typo. Try to copy and paste the path from the properties of the file.

Comment: Why double slash? A single slash should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

I just found that I had a small letter i in Images, instead of capitalized. Corrected this, and it worked fine. Be careful, Linux is case sensitive with file names.