# File Not Found When Using Includegraphics

Tags: graphics, pdftex

I am writing a mathematical paper, and in it I need to include certain images relevant to the topic. However, when I try to do so, I receive an error code, and nothing I have found on the subject is giving me any insight on how to relieve this error. I have the following;

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {C:/Texpics} }


\begin{document}
\includegraphics{img.png}
```

And I receive;

```
! LaTeX Error: File `img.png' not found.
```

Any advice would be appreciated. Working in both TeXworks and Texmaker gives the same result.

Comment: Put the file `img.png` in the working directory (in the same directory that the `.tex` file), remove `\graphicspath{ {C:/Texpics} }` and use \includegraphics{img} without the `.png`. It work  now?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need it have:

```
\graphicspath{{C:/Texpics/}}
```

Else are you sure that the figure exists in the directory?

Comment: @TeXnician: Adding the missing slash often is an answer as it was here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/367811/9057